# Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm

Tags: php

```
function fnEncrypt($key,$string){

    return  base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5($key)));
    }
```

**and**

```
fnEncrypt("6abd9b547f8d23b367dff1fc4g7ad457b7f7f85e","AB10|13213123");
```

I got warning msg like

> Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm

How to solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your key is too long, just like the warning message indicates.

As of 5.6.0, [`mcrypt_encrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php):

> Invalid `key` and `iv` sizes are no longer accepted. `mcrypt_encrypt()` will now throw a warning and return `FALSE` if the inputs are invalid. Previously keys and IVs were padded with `'\0'` bytes to the next valid size.

The key size for AES-256 is 32 bytes; your string is 40 characters in length.

Also, look at [Example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#refsect1-function.mcrypt-encrypt-examples) on that page. It indicates that

> the key should be random binary, use scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2 to convert a string into a key

That means, don't use a string directly as the key (like you're doing). Not only is a key-derivation function more secure, but it will allow you to use any length of passphrase you wish, while generating the correct key length.